# iniciando con qt

Tags: qt

No puedo crear un nuevo proyecto en qt en lenguaje c++

El proyecto que quiero es **Plain C++ application**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

dice que no esta configurado, que debo configurar?

Comment: Según la captura, no tienes configurado ningún kit, lo que me hace pensar en que no tienes instalado Qt. Si vas a `Tools->Options->Qt Versions` ¿Que versión te aparece?

Comment: Si vas a usar C++ estándar, sin Qt,  al menos tienes que configurar el compilador y el depurador.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Al momento de instalar Qt tienes que ver que compilador vas a instalar en este caso puedes usar **MinGW** si es Windows  y en Linux **GCC**.

Al parecer tu solo instalaste el QtCreator solo el entorno de Qt más no las demás herramientas del entorno.

Cuando instalas Qt aparecerá la siguiente ventana en el apartado de **Tools** agregas que compilador usaras ya sea de 32 bits o 64 bits y la versión que ocuparas.
Por defecto te instala la versión de 32 bits cuando  estas instalando el entorno de trabajo Qt más no solo el QtCreator.

[image: Aquí cuando instalas marca las casillas del compilador que ocuparas.]

Esta es la guía de instalación en español que utilice para instalarlo espero te pueda ayudar.

[Qt_Guía de instalación](http://isa.uniovi.es/~ialvarez/Curso/descargas/InstalarQt.pdf)

Saludos.

Comment: por favor añade lo relevante del enlace aquí, tu respuesta es parcialmente válida; por que aunque le indicas que debe hacer al solo poner el link si en un futuro esa página deja de existir la info. se pierde; entonces dale editar y añade lo relevante al final solo deja el enlace como créditos al autor original

Comment: Claro tienes razón .